# What is the point in setting a slice's capacity?

Tags: go, slice

In Golang, we can use the builtin `make()` function to create a slice with a given initial length and capacity.

Consider the following lines, the slice's length is set to 1, and its capacity 3:

```
func main() {
    var slice = make([]int, 1, 3)
    slice[0] = 1
    slice = append(slice, 6, 0, 2, 4, 3, 1)
    fmt.Println(slice)
}
```

I was surprised to see that this program prints:

> [1 6 0 2 4 3 1]

This got me wondering- what is the point of initially defining a slice's capacity if `append()` can simply blow past it? Are there performance gains for setting a sufficiently large capacity?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

A slice is really just a fancy way to manage an underlying array. It automatically tracks size, and re-allocates new space as needed.

As you append to a slice, the runtime doubles its capacity every time it exceeds its current capacity. It has to copy all of the elements to do that. If you know how big it will be before you start, you can avoid a few copy operations and memory allocations by grabbing it all up front.

When you `make` a slice providing capacity, you set the **initial capacity**, not any kind of **limit**.

See [this blog post on slices](https://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals#TOC_5.) for some interesting internal details of slices.

Comment: At a certain point, it stops doubling and starts increasing in 25% increments. I think that happens after 1024 elements.

Comment: It's not just the copy op that takes time, it's also the alloc.

Comment: As Stephen mentioned, it's not as simple as doubling, but here's an interesting case study. I ran some benchmarks recently (1.15.x). Nil slices are an absolute worst case scenario. Until it reaches `cap: 10` it only adds a single element, then begins doubling (until 1000 or so). So if you begin with a nil slice, or make with 0 cap, then add 10 elements, it has to alloc and copy EVERY iteration. I personally encourage always set cap. You can usually derive the exact n from another value, or at the very least can set it initially to 10 to avoid those first 10 alloc/copy. The benchmarks were bad.

Answer (score 18):

A `slice` is a wonderful abstraction of a simple `array`. You get all sorts of nice features, but deep down at its core, lies an `array`. (I explain the following in reverse order for a reason). Therefore, if/when you specify a `capacity` of `3`, deep down, an array of length `3` is allocated in memory, which you can `append` up to without having it need to reallocate memory. This attribute is optional in the `make` command, but note that a `slice` will always have a `capacity` whether or not you choose to specify one. If you specify a `length` (which always exists as well), the `slice` be indexable up to that length. The rest of the `capacity` is hidden away behind the scenes so it does not have to allocate **an entirely new array** when `append` is used.

Here is an example to better explain the mechanics.

`s := make([]int, 1, 3)`

The underlying `array` will be allocated with `3` of the zero value of `int` (which is `0`):

`[0,0,0]`

However, the `length` is set to `1`, so the slice itself will only print `[0]`, and if you try to index the second or third value, it will `panic`, as the `slice`'s mechanics do not allow it. If you `s = append(s, 1)` to it, you will find that it has actually been created to contain `zero` values up to the `length`, and you will end up with `[0,1]`. At this point, you can `append` once more before the entire underlying `array` is filled, and another `append` will force it to allocate a new one and copy all the values over with a doubled capacity. This is actually a rather expensive operation.

**Therefore** the short answer to your question is that preallocating the `capacity` can be used to vastly improve the efficiency of your code. Especially so if the `slice` is either going to end up very large, or contains complex `structs` (or both), as the `zero` value of a `struct` is effectively the `zero` values of every single one of its `fields`. This is not because it would avoid allocating those values, as it has to anyway, but because `append` would have to reallocate new `array`s full of these zero values each time it would need to resize the underlying array.

Short playground example: https://play.golang.org/p/LGAYVlw-jr

Answer (score 13):

As others have already said, using the `cap` parameter can avoid unnecessary allocations. To give a sense of the performance difference, imagine you have a `[]float64` of random values and want a new slice that filters out values that are not above, say, `0.5`.

**Naive approach - no len or cap param**

```
func filter(input []float64) []float64 {
    ret := make([]float64, 0)
    for _, el := range input {
        if el > .5 {
            ret = append(ret, el)
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```

**Better approach - using cap param**

```
func filterCap(input []float64) []float64 {
    ret := make([]float64, 0, len(input))
    for _, el := range input {
        if el > .5 {
            ret = append(ret, el)
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```

**Benchmarks (n=10)**

```
filter     131 ns/op    56 B/op  3 allocs/op
filterCap   56 ns/op    80 B/op  1 allocs/op
```

Using `cap` made the program 2x+ faster and reduced the number of allocations from 3 to 1. Now what happens at scale?

**Benchmarks (n=1,000,000)**

```
filter     9630341 ns/op    23004421 B/op    37 allocs/op
filterCap  6906778 ns/op     8003584 B/op     1 allocs/op
```

The speed difference is still significant (~1.4x) thanks to 36 fewer calls to `runtime.makeslice`. However, the bigger difference is the memory allocation (~4x less).

**Even better - calibrating the cap**

You may have noticed in the first benchmark that `cap` makes the overall memory allocation worse (`80B vs 56B`). This is because you allocate 10 slots but only need, on average, 5 of them. This is why you don't want to set `cap` unnecessarily high. Given what you know about your program, you may be able to calibrate the capacity. In this case, we can estimate that our filtered slice will need 50% as many slots as the original slice.

```
func filterCalibratedCap(input []float64) []float64 {
    ret := make([]float64, 0, len(input)/2)
    for _, el := range input {
        if el > .5 {
            ret = append(ret, el)
        }
    }
    return ret
}
```

Unsurprisingly, this calibrated `cap` allocates 50% as much memory as its predecessor, so that's ~8x improvement on the naive implementation at 1m elements.

**Another option - using direct access instead of append**

If you are looking to shave even more time off a program like this, initialize with the `len` parameter (and ignore the cap parameter), access the new slice directly instead of using append, then throw away all the slots you don't need.

```
func filterLen(input []float64) []float64 {
    ret := make([]float64, len(input))
    var counter int
    for _, el := range input {
        if el > .5 {
            ret[counter] = el
            counter++
        }
    }
    return ret[:counter]
}
```

This is ~10% faster than `filterCap` at scale. However, in addition to being more complicated, this pattern does not provide the same safety as `cap` if you try and calibrate the memory requirement.

- With `cap` calibration, if you underestimate the total capacity required, then the program will automatically allocate more when it needs it.
- With this approach, if you underestimate the total `len` required, the program will fail. In this example, if you initialize as `ret := make([]float64, len(input)/2)`, and it turns out that `len(output) > len(input)/2`, then at some point the program will try to access a non-existent slot and panic.

Comment: I really like your answer here. I'm curious what version of go you used for these benchmarks. I recently found that `n=10` is a subtly nefarious worst case (when `cap` starts at 0), but it didn't show as such in your benchmark. I found that a slice with `cap < 10` only adds a single element when `makeslice` is called. But your benchmark only showed 3 allocs with `n=10`. I'll have to read the changelogs again.

Answer (score 0):

Each time you add an item to a slice that has `len(mySlice) == cap(mySlice)`, the underlying data structure is replaced with a larger structure.

```golang
fmt.Printf("Original Capacity: %v", cap(mySlice))  // Output: 8
mySlice = append(mySlice, myNewItem)
fmt.Printf("New Capacity: %v", cap(mySlice))  // Output: 16
```

Here, `mySlice` is replaced (through the assignment operator) with a new slice containing all the elements of the original `mySlice`, plus `myNewItem`, plus some room (capacity) to grow without triggering this resize.

As you can imagine, this resizing operation is computationally non-trivial.

Quite often, all the resize operations can be avoided **if** you know how many items you will need to store in `mySlice`. If you have this foreknowledge, you can set the capacity of the original slice upfront and avoid all the resize operations.

(In practice, it's quite often possible to know how many items will be added to a collection; especially when transforming data from one format to another.)